# Android Studio java - app crashes using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: java, android

**NOTE:** *I have resubmitted, same problem but slightly different context in order to simplify* **[11.9.2021]**

A text file is stored in the `sheet music` directory of the phone.  The app is to open this `.txt` files into an `EditText` field.  This is a proof of concept that this can be accomplished.

I have taken code example [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/09/example-of-using-intentactionopendocume.html) and tried modifying it so that it will open the file `anticipation_lyrics.txt` in the EditText field `@+id/editText`.

Once clicking "Use This Folder" and then "Allow" the app crashes.

This is the logic:

1. user clicks the button to launch directory picker
2. the code opens a document tree picker
3. The user can then select a directory
4. the app will open the file `anticipation_lyrics.txt` (already stored within that directory)
5. code checks if the file exists
6. the code will read its contents into a string builder and set the text of the edit text field `editText` to the contents of the file

I believe the app crashes here:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri)
```

however no error is generated.

`Manifest` has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is the complete java code:

```
package com.enetapplications.displayfilecontent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DisplayFileContentActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE = 2;

    TextView textInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        Button btnOpen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opendocument);
        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check if the result is OK and if the request code matches the constant for opening a document tree
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) {
            Uri uriTree = data.getData(); // Retrieve the URI representing the selected directory

            // Get the EditText field.
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

            // Get the URI of the file "anticipation_lyrics.txt" within the chosen directory.
            Uri fileUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uriTree, "anticipation_lyrics.txt");

            // Open the file for reading and set its content in the EditText field
            try (InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri)) {
                // Read the contents of the file into a string builder.
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }

                // Set the text of the EditText field to the contents of the file.
                editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error reading the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Notify the user about an error in file reading
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are no error messages either from the code or debugger

Comment: So where do you call `launch`? The launcher doesn't do anything until you launch it

Comment: `Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(uri.toString().replace("/tree/", "/document/"));` ???? Can you tell why you mess around with a valid uri? This looks very nasty.

Comment: You did not tell us that you want the user to choose a directory and having obtained a valid uri for a directory you mess around with it trying to build a file uri for a file in that directory. Not possible the way you do it. Very nasty!

Comment: For those following the thread this is a re-submitted query, perhaps I should have started a new thread but it is the same problem but in a more simplified format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was using `DocumentFile`.  Below is the proof-of-concept example of opening a `.txt` file into an `EditText` field:

```
package com.enetapplications.displayfilecontent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DisplayFileContentActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE = 2;
    TextView textInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("DisplayFileContentActivityz", "(DisplayFileContentActivity) line #28");
        textInfo = findViewById(R.id.info);
        Button btnOpen = findViewById(R.id.opendocument);
        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(v -> openDocumentTree());
    }

    private void openDocumentTree() {
        Log.d("DisplayFileContentActivityz", "(DisplayFileContentActivity) line #34");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        Log.d("DisplayFileContentActivityz", "(DisplayFileContentActivity) line #36");
        startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("DisplayFileContentActivityz", "(DisplayFileContentActivity) line #43");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) {
            Uri uriTree = data.getData();
            Log.d("DisplayFileContentActivityz", "(DisplayFileContentActivity) line #47");
            EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
            Log.d("DisplayFileContentActivityz", "(DisplayFileContentActivity) line #50");

            DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uriTree);
            DocumentFile file = pickedDir.findFile("anticipation_lyrics.txt");

            if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
                Log.d("DisplayFileContentActivityz", "(DisplayFileContentActivity) line #58 file = " + file);
                Toast.makeText(this, "The file 'anticipation_lyrics.txt' does not exist.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            try (InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(file.getUri())) {
                Log.d("DisplayFileContentActivityz", "(DisplayFileContentActivity) line #56");
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                editText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error reading the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```